# Apple wallet - create cards from the application

Tags: ios, swift, apple-wallet

I am building a mobile application and i want to use the apple wallet functionality for storing custom cards(like the boarding tickets and discount cards). My aim is to create a card and add QR code to it, save it to the wallet. All of this should happen dynamically, this means that from the app the user can add multiple cards to the wallet. Is the there a doc about the wallet api and how i can achieve that, or if someone have done something like this before. Thank you and if i am not descriptive enough, i can provide more info.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/PassKit_PG/Creating.html